# What's your Gamertag/Platform?

Tags: video-games, social-network, wiki

It's more social than sound design, but I thought it might be cool to have a list of the gamers on here. So list your platform and tag, maybe include your favorite online game (or promote your own). As with other lists like this, mark your answer as **community wiki**. See you guys online!

---

PS3 - sfxmonkey

currently playing - [Battlefield: Bad Company 2](http://www.battlefieldbadcompany2.com/) / [COD Black Ops](http://www.callofduty.com/) / [Civilization Revolution](http://www.civilizationrevolution.com/)

Answer (score 1):

SteamID: copiousx

Origin (BF3): Kilometerrs

Games: TF2, L4D 1 & 2, Civ III, Civ 5

Btw, BF3's sound is a-MAY-zing.

Answer (score 0):

Xbox: GDOG69XXX
Games: COD: MW2, Puzzle Quest 2, Mass Effect 2.

Answer (score 0):

RAGameSound...

Recently, it's been mostly the Civ series. I'm very excited to start playing Civ 5

Comment: Ehm, that's the PS3. My STEAM id is Notafraud

Add me! Let's play! Nothing like talking shop over a game.

Answer (score 0):

PS3: Sraiphin - and I've been playing through the Uncharted games lately
Steam: sraiphin - and I only have Dirt2 (because it came with the graphics card for my PC...lol)

Comment: Uncharted blows me away.

Answer (score 0):

My steam ID is Samuraipanda. lots of different games. I play xbox as well but I've had problems with the xbox recently so I don't play it very often.

Answer (score 0):

SteamID: colinski

PC:  Day of Defeat, Myst games, Age of Empires - mostly old games and simulators like Rollercoaster Tychoon and Sim City.  Btw, anybody wants to trade old PC games... yes indeed I'm interested.

PS2:  Tekken Tag, various others.

Gamecube:  Pikmin, Zelda games

I'm going backwards in time when it comes to gaming- getting ready to construct my first MAME powered multicade cabinet and have been buying a lot of SNES/NES games.

Answer (score 0):

Xbox 360:  The Mung Pie

Halo
Call of Duty
Sports Games (Hockey)

Answer (score 0):

PS3: StarskyUK

Steam: ade2j

Currently playing Fifa 2011 & F1 on PS3.

On the PC I'm on still playing on CoD 4, Company of Heroes, FM2011 and CoD 7 now and then.

Answer (score 0):

XBOX360: noiseboy55

Mainly Fifa!

Answer (score 0):

PSN: RAGameSound
Steam: Notafraud

Answer (score 0):

PS3-Belladelmuerto

COD Black Ops / Civilization Revolution

Answer (score 0):

PS3: bondjonbond

Mortal Kombat baby!!!!

Answer (score 0):

SonikSplash

PS:3  Black Ops

Answer (score 0):

360: TheFaderJockey

I'm a casual gamer: Portal 2, TF2, Borderlands, lots of single player games.

Answer (score 0):

360: Link2803

Pretty much glued to Battlefield: BC2 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

xbox : THIRD EARTH 187
black ops

Answer (score 0):

Steamid- kuttekamine

PC-
RUSE, Battlefield bad company 2, Microsoft Flight sim x, NFs series.

RUSE has awesome sound design, when you zoom out completely to war room view with you game map looking like a war  strategy map, you can hear the machine and office sounds, as you zoom in, you pass the skies, and hear ambience and as you zoom in closer, you can hear the war ambience and feel like in the battle. Best war RTS game.

Answer (score 0):

xbox: mattesque

Mostly just been playing single player stuff lately. And researching other games for work.

Answer (score 0):

PS3 - gorillachest

I'm another one who only plays Bad Company 2!

Answer (score 0):

xbox: SolarUnion33

Been playing Halo Reach and GoW3.

Answer (score 0):

Battlefield 3 on pc, awesome sound design! FYI,

Battlelog: sgtfondle

Steam: left 4 dead 2 mostly and battlefield bad company 2
Steam name: caloof

=]